# Converting varchar to number

Tags: database, oracle

I recently did a TO_NUMBER(column_name) and it converted it to a number successfully. My question is in regards to the data type, it is data type NUMBER in Oracle, originally the column is a varchar. Is it possible to do a TO_NUMBER conversion that would result in a data type of NUMBER(19,0) rather than just a NUMBER data type?

Here is my statement:

```
select column1, cast(regexp_replace(column1, 'hi') as NUMBER(19,0)) TEST from table1
```

However when I try to create a view with this I get:

Error(s) parsing SQL: Unexpected token at 63 near ,0)) TEST from table1.
Unexpected token at 65 near )) TEST from table1.

Is cast not possible to create a view?.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CAST function: `CAST(TO_NUMBER(column_name) AS NUMBER(19, 0))`

Comment: Hello I have edited my post, unable to create a view with cast...just a select statement it works but not when I try to create a view out of it.

Comment: I have no problem to create view with the same expression.

Comment: Ah it must be a sqldeveloper bug...i ran it from sqlplus* and it worked like a charm thanks for all the help!